# How To Download Kali linux Old ISO From Official Sources Like kali.org

Tags: kali-linux, iso

Hey Stack Overflow Community I Have been Huge Fan Of Kali Linux as all the development pakage is preinstalled plus using windows you have distraction like playing games so i generally use kali for penetration testing learning and for the development as all python 3 c shell are preinstalled but i did n't like the fancy new kali arrival after 2020.1 so is there a way to get old kali iso like 2017,18,19 from the official source because of disk file from untrusted could reverse engineer to make it maleware i do know oldkali.org like ftp but i do not know it as official if it do reply

Answer (score 2):

All the old Kali Linux ISOs (from kali-1.0.0 to kali-2021.1) can be found [here](http://old.kali.org/kali-images/): `http://old.kali.org/kali-images/`. Every iso come with the signed checksum files it will be used to check  the downloaded images.

Answer (score 0):

Some advice, try searching the web to see if your concern is already addressed before posting here. This site also gives a lot of helpful guidance on when and how to ask questions--as well as how and when *not* to. Please read it.

Here is a link to my Google search that turned up multiple answers and even the official Kali (old) archives: [Google Search: kali linux download official old](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-e&q=kali%20linux%20download%20official%20old)

Specifically, old.kali.org is documented by Kali (see their README.md file) as the official root mirror to download older images, and I can see images on their site as old as 1.0 (from 2014).